# "Target class [Modules\\Admins\\Controllers\\AdminController] does not exist."

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, design-patterns, laravel-8

I'm developing an e-commerce website using Laravel 8, And I tried to change on Laravel folders structure I've put views folder inside new path **modules/admins** which works fine, and I've also created a Models folder in the *modules/admins* path which works fine, however, I am having trouble with the controllers folder.

I still have the app/http/controllers/Controller.php, but now I've created a folder called Controllers inside the *modules* folder, and in it I have a controller called AdminController

**error message:** *"Target class [Modules\Admins\Controllers\AdminController] does not exist."*

**project structure**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXW8y.jpg)

**AdminController file**

```
namespace Modules\Admins\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Http\Traits\ApiDesignTrait;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\{
    Hash, Validator
};
class AdminController extends BaseController
{
    public function test()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**route.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Modules\Admins\Controllers\AdminController;

Route::post('/test',  [AdminController::class, 'test']);
```

**BaseController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class BaseController extends Controller
{

}
```

**Controller.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Comment: If the namespace is correct, try running composer dump-autoload in the terminal as well.

Comment: I execute the command but no change occurs

Comment: @zihad I think I need a way to register the path of controller, or change the default path in somewhere but I don't know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your defined namespace is outside of app, you should **autoload** it in your `composer.json` file.

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
        "Modules\\": "Modules/"
    }
},
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload` and it should work fine.

Comment: There is a bad expression I will fix it, where the admin folder is inside the modules folder and inside the admin folder, I've created views, models, and controllers folders I will edit question.

Comment: @mahmoudmohamed I added the update. It will solve your issue.

Comment: finally its working good thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the namespace of the route file in the route service provider class
in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` you need to edit the boot function

```
/**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace('Modules\\Admins\\Controllers')
                ->group(base_path('routes/route.php'));
        });
    }
```

in your route.php you can do this

```
Route::post('/test',  'AdminController@test');
```

**if you dont want to edit the service provider**

```
Route::namespace('Modules\\Admins\\Controllers')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/test', 'AdminController@test');
});
```